# Infinitesimal displacement when rotating a vector

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, rotational-kinematics

I found this in a kinematics book and this section is on angular velocity, and since no diagram is given I assumed that they are describing something that looks like this:
[image: 1]

> Consider an infinitesimal rotation through an angle $\text{d}\varphi$ about the axis $OO'$ whose unit vector we shall denote as $\hat{\mathbf{e}}$. In virtue of this rotation, a point whose position vector was originally $\mathbf{r}$ will describe an arc of a circle of radius $r\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between  $\hat{\mathbf{e}}$ and $\mathbf{r}$. **This displacement $\text{d}\mathbf{r}$ will be of length $r\sin\theta \text{d}\varphi$ and will be perpendicular to both $\hat{\mathbf{e}}$ and $\mathbf{r}$.** Therefore, $\text{d}\mathbf{r}$ is parallel to $\hat{\mathbf{e}}\times\mathbf{r}$ and is of $\text{d}\varphi$ times its length.

But if I am correct in what the diagram is like, then how does the part in bold make sense since $\mathbf{r}$ can't be perpendicular to $\text{d}\mathbf{r}$ and how/why can $\text{d}\mathbf{r}$ equal $r\sin\theta \text{d}\varphi$?

Comment: Why do think that that $\delta{\bf r}$ cannot be perpendicular to both ${\bf e}$ and ${\bf r }$? The figure shows that  $\delta{\bf r}=( \delta \varphi {\bf e})\times {\bf r}$ which *is* perpendicular to both ${\bf e}$ and ${\bf r }$.  Here "$\times$" is the vector product and hence the factor of $\sin \theta$

Comment: Oh sorry, I see that now. But what about δr = r sin Φ δθ
How does that work?

Comment: The radius of the circle is $R=  r\sin \theta$ so a small rotation  $\delta \varphi$ gives a displacement of magnitude $|\delta {\bf r}|= R \delta \varphi= r\sin\theta  \delta \varphi$

Comment: @SilverBlade Hi, I have formatted your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), which is the standard for this site.

Comment: @mikestone If dφ / time = angular velocity, then why later in the book does it say $ \dot r = \dot dφ  e × r $, why are the r and e needed?

Answer (score 0):

The diagram can be interpreted as representing the motion of an object (located at point (A) moving in a horizontal circle (assuming the axis (O) to (O') is vertical.  The radius of the circle is R = r sin(θ).  The (r) is just a position vector which locates the object relative to point (O).  The infinitesimal displacement dr = R dφ.